# How do I configure the HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION environment variable?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get the husky_gazebo package running on ROS Indigo. But when I try running :

"roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch"

I encounter an error that says :

"environment variable 'HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION' is not set"

Can somebody help me out please? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248760/how-do-i-configure-the-husky_gazebo_description-environment-variable?/) by [Amrita Suresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28256/amrita-suresh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per the tutorial in http://wiki.ros.org/husky_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Husky , Step 2:

```
$ export HUSKY_GAZEBO_DESCRIPTION=$(rospack find husky_gazebo)/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro
```

---

Originally posted by [Arif Rahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/12751/arif-rahman/) with karma: 48 on 2017-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0